# How do I charge early-bird rates on my Cognito form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I use Cognito Forms to allow my customers to sign up and pay online for Yoga sessions.  I run an early bird special rate available until a specific date and then sessions are full price from that date until the start date. Instead of making a note in my calendar to manually go in to change the pricing info, is there a way to set it so the price will automatically change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the developers for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) and will be glad to explain how to include Early-Bird rates on your forms.

In the Price field where you enter the amount, you can also enter calculations by starting with an "=". The [online help](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations) provides details on different types of calculations, but here is the specific calculation that should work for your needs:

=DateTime.Today < "11/22/2014" ? 65 : 75

[image]

To explain, the "=" at the beginning lets Cognito know you are entering a calculation, not just a number. DateTime.Today will always return the current day. Comparing this to dates, in the format of "mm/dd/yyyy" in quotes will allow you to see if the day is before your cutoff date. Then the somewhat cryptic ? and : allow you to specify what the price should be if the date is before or after the cutoff date.

I hope this helps!